# me puedes ayudar con este ejercicio de leardnyounode (mi primer i/o)?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

/* Escribe un programa que, usando una llamada síncrona al sistema de  archivos, lea un archivo recibido por argumento e imprima a consola la  cantidad de saltos de línea ('\n') que contiene. Similar a ejecutar cat
file | wc -l.
El programa recibirá la ruta al archivo como único argumento.*/

```
var fs = require('fs');

var NumeroDeLineas = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2], 'utf-8')
var lineas = NumeroDeLineas/*.toString()*/.split('\n').lenght - 1;

console.log(lineas);
```

Comment: Hola Cristian, me alegro que encontraras tu respuesta. Como referencia para el futuro: las preguntas pidiendo ayuda con la depuración de un programa deben incluir el código, una descripción del mismo y los errores/dificultades que te estés encontrando. Tu pregunta tiene los dos primeros (lo cual es genial), pero le falta el error. Con el cual seguramente te habrías dado cuenta del fallo directamente porque sería un error de sintaxis al no existir `lenght` (algunos IDEs incluso sugerirán el cambio por `length`).

Comment: gracias parce si es cierto el error estaba en lenght != length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

con mis compañeros estuve analizando el código y dedujimos que el error estaba en que no es **lenght** y es **length**

```
var fs = require('fs');

var NumeroDeLineas = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2], 'utf-8')
var lineas = NumeroDeLineas.toString().split('\n').length - 1;

console.log(lineas);
```